# Dependency inject Class with class methods

Tags: objective-c, unit-testing, dependency-injection

I have a class that has only class methods

```
//FileManager.h

+(void)writeData:(NSData*)data toFile:(NSString*)filePath;
//...
//some more class methods
```

I use this class inside another one

```
//AttachmentsRepository.m

-(void)newAttachment:(NSData*)attachmentData{
    //some code
    NSString * generatedPath = @"/some/generated/path";
    [FileManager writeData:attachmentData toFile:generatedPath];
}
```

Now I am writing tests for *AttachmentRepository* and was wondering how to inject *FileManager*.

What I use is the "extract and override call" technique:

```
//AttachmentsRepository.m

-(void)newAttachment:(NSData*)attachmentData{
    //some code
    NSString * generatedPath = @"/some/generated/path";
    [[self getFileManagerClass] writeData:attachmentData toFile:generatedPath];
}
-(Class)getFileManagerClass{
    return [FileManager class];
}
```

Now in my test I just stub out `getFileManagerClass` to return `[FakeFileManager class]`

What is a better solution? This is legacy code but lets say that we are writing it now. How should the *FileManager* dependency be implemented.

PS. I want to use a fake because I would like to avoid writing to disk when testing the *AttachmentRepository* class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From "Working Effectively With Legacy Code" by Michael C. Feathers I found out about the "Introduce Instance Delegator" technique.

Basically we duplicate the methods we need and make them instance methods. Their body is just a call to the class/static method. Then we use the instance class as argument to the constructor or the method that needs to use it.

```
//FileManager.h

+(void)writeData:(NSData*)data toFile:(NSString*)filePath;
-(void)writeData:(NSData*)data toFile:(NSString*)filePath;
//...

//FileManager.m
-(void)writeData:(NSData*)data toFile:(NSString*)filePath;{
    [FileManager writeData:data toFile:filePath];
}
```

In *AttachmentsRepository*:

```
//AttachmentsRepository.m
-(instance) initWithFileManager:(FileManager *)fileManager{
    if(self = [super init]){
     _fileManager = fileManager
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)newAttachment:(NSData*)attachmentData{
    //some code
    NSString * generatedPath = @"/some/generated/path";
    [self.fileManager writeData:attachmentData toFile:generatedPath];
}
```

The conclusion seems to be that the *FileManager* class shouldn't have had class/static methods but instance methods instead when it was implemented at the start.

All this kinda makes me feel awkward - making methods that can be class/static to be instead on instance level.